# How do I publish just 1 HTML file in author instance of aem server?

Tags: content-management-system, adobe, aem

I want to create a simple HTML file

```
/content/1.html
```

in the author instance in the aem server and publish it. How should I publish it - either through the UI or command-line is fine?

Comment: a side note: you don't create html files in AEM. you create pages using templates and components. `html` is just one of the extensions using which AEM would use the appropriate renderer to serve content in the right format (html in this case).

Answer (score 3):

Two options for easier, to handle from browser itself,

1) Go to [tree activation](http://localhost:4502/etc/replication/treeactivation.html) page and select the page path which you want to activate and click on the **Activate** button use the check boxes ( Only Modified, Only Activated, Ignore Deactivated) according to your need,

[image: Treeactivation]

2) Go to [crx/de console](http://localhost:4502/crx/de/index.jsp) select the page that you want to activate under the content node. use the right side **Replication** Tab `Replicate` button to replicate the node.

> Note that when using this node level replicate action you need to
>   activate all the child/individual nodes that are required to your page
>   content.

[image: CRXDE Replication]

There are several other ways of doing replication by code, CURL, etc. as which one to use depends on your comfort levels.

Comment: Just think it's worth highlighting that tree activation and node activations do not check for dependencies thay have not been activated unlike the activation UI.

Answer (score 0):

[package manager Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9DbX.png)

Simplest ways are already mentioned above but i am mentioning one more way .
check it out if you are more comfortable with it.

You can replicate it or publish your file using Package manager.
1.Goto http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr
2.Goto your package[/content/1.html] and edit it.
3.Save it and choose the replicate option under the more tab.

Answer (score 0):

In the page side kick, you click on properties then "activate"